# Primary display is not detecting in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution

In my desktop PC I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 several times. But it never detect the primary monitor. It is not getting correct resolution. I changed the monitor, but result is same. How can I fix this?

[image: Display settings]

[image: xrandr]

Comment: Did you install the correct driver for your graphics card?

Comment: I am new for ubuntu. And I did not install graphic driver. I thought ubuntu would detect it. I believe this issue came just after upgrade the OS. Before upgrading It had detected correct display and configured to correct resolution.

Comment: I am not fond of upgrading. In the past I had problems with left-over files that interfered, so I always install fresh versions and never had problems. But that does not help you now. There are many reasons why  the monitor is not properly detected: the cable inside the monitor cable maybe damaged, try another; the driver is not behaving properly, re-install it. Perhaps the easiest first step might be to boot from Live USB and see if the monitor is properly recognized.

Comment: I tried installing drivers. But nothing happens. I tried running Live CD also when I am installing the OS. At that time also it did not work with proper resolution. Same as this. So I guess this would be a hardware problem then. Isn't it?

Comment: I  hesitate to give a definite yes or no without proof. Are you able to replace the cable, the monitor or both?

Comment: No it is not possible for me because I am not authorized for that in this PC. Any way thanks for the help man.